# EF Core included nested self-referencing list

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-core-2.0

I have an entity looking like this:

```
public class Comment
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime PublishedDate { get; set; }
    public string CommentText { get; set; }
    public bool IsEdited { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Comment> Replies { get; set; }



    public int? ParentBlogId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ParentBlogId")]
    public BlogPost ParentBlog { get; set; }

    public Guid? ParentCommentId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ParentCommentId")]
    public Comment ParentComment { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

Now as you see this contains an ICollection of the same type. So a comment can have multiple comments under it. When I want to load all these in a nice nested list I tried using this:

```
var comments = await _context.Comments
                .Include(x => x.User)
                .Include(x => x.Replies)
                 .ThenInclude(x => x.User).ToListAsync();
```

The problem is that this only loads 2 levels deep. So if I have a structure like this:

```
Comment
Comment
    Comment
        Comment
        Comment
    Comment
Comment
```

It will only load the first 2 levels:

```
Comment
Comment
    Comment
    Comment
Comment
```

How can I make it include all the replies of subreplies?

Comment: Have you tried these?: http://codingcanvas.com/loading-nested-entities-in-entityframework/

Comment: None of these will work. Eager loading doens't work as demonstrated in my example. Neither can projection due to the Select statement. Explicit loading won't work because I want a list, not a single object. And Lazy Loading does not exist in EF Core

Comment: I'm pretty sure `_context.Comments.ToList()` will load all levels. Are you sure you don't apply some filter?

Comment: Or to load all grandchildren of a single comment, something like `_context.Comments.Where( r => loadedComment.Replies.Select(c => c.Id).ToList().Contains(r.ParentCommentId).AsEnumerable().Last();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it by calling a recursive method:

```
    public async Task<List<Comment>> GetAsync(int blogId)
    {
        var comments = await _context.Comments
            .Include(x => x.User)
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.PublishedDate)
            .Where(x => x.ParentBlog.Id == blogId && !x.IsDeleted).ToListAsync();

        comments = await GetRepliesAsync(comments);


        return comments;
    }


    private async Task<List<Comment>> GetRepliesAsync(List<Comment> comments)
    {
        foreach (var comment in comments)
        {
            var replies = await GetFromParentIdAsync(comment.Id);
            if (replies != null)
            {
                comment.Replies = await GetRepliesAsync(replies.ToList());
            }
        }

        return comments;
    }
```

Comment: I've been migrating a project to .NET Core 3.1 and the only frustration was dealing with EntityFrameworkCore. breaking changes in the API and lacking features compared to EF6. The EntityFramework Plus library helps with some things like IncludeFilter but I've been losing my mind over how to load self-referencing tables with a filter applied. This helped, although it's not ideal because of too many DB hits and queries. The next version of EFCore supports Include filters, we'll see how it plays out. Thank you.